# Failed to start the Marketing Automation Engine service - Sitecore 10 installation failed on Windows 11

Tags: sitecore-client, marketing-automation

Failed to start the Marketing Automation Engine service - `Sitecore 10 installation failed on Windows 11`

```
Starting Marketing Automation Engine...
2022-02-07 15:54:34 ERR Error initializing XConnect client.
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.ConnectionTimeoutException: A task was canceled. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
```

Comment: It appears like you solved this issue. You may want to post an answer to your own question so that people can see the answer easily?

Comment: This also applies to Sitecore 9.3 running on Windows 11

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:** The issue was resolved by disabling TLS 1.3 over TCP.

New-Item `'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Server'`
-Force | Out-Null

New-ItemProperty `-path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Server'`
-name 'Enabled' -value '0' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null

New-ItemProperty `-path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.3\Server'`
-name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null

[image]